# ParseCrashReporting error _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFDevice" Apple Mach-O linker error

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios8, xcode6

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFDevice", referenced from: objc-class-ref in ParseCrashReporting(PFCrashReporter.o)

I was using parse cloud and analytic for a few months now I added parse crash reporting and I am getting this error, how can I fix it?

I already added these libraries:

```
libstdc++6.dylib
libsqlite3.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems in addition to adding libraries, I needed to update Parse.framework and Bolts.framework in my project and this solved the problem.